# How can I create composition scoping by using metadata in MEF?

Tags: c#, mef

My goal is to share instances of objects for some part of application. There are lots of different kind of modules inside one container so there have to be dynamic way to define which instances should be shared in which scope.

The idea is working quite fine when I'm using Filtered catalogs,  CompositionScopeDefinition with PartMetadata attribute. The PartMetadatas are used by FilteredCatalogs.

```
var fullCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();

// lots of different kind of modules added inside aggregate catalog here

var globalLevelCatalog = fullCatalog.Filter(cpd => 
    !cpd.ContainsPartMetadataWithKey("Scope.App") || 
    cpd.ContainsPartMetadataWithKey("Scope.Global")
);

var appLevelCatalog = fullCatalog.Filter(cpd => 
    cpd.ContainsPartMetadataWithKey("Scope.App")
);

var appLevelDefinition = new CompositionScopeDefinition(appLevelCatalog, null);

var globalDefinition = new CompositionScopeDefinition(
    globalLevelCatalog, new[] { appLevelDefinition }
);

var container = new CompositionContainer(globalDefinition);
```

**Question**

I have found that I can use **PartMetadataAttribute** only in concrete class which has exported. Is there any way to add PartMetadata from base / abstract class?

If there is no way to do that - Is there other way to do this kind of dynamic scoping?

```
[PartMetadata("Scope.App", true)]  // will not be part of Metadata
public abstract class AppBase : IApp
{

}

// The PartMetadata has to be defined here so it is part of Metadata
[Export(typeof(IApp))]
public class TheApp
{

}
```

Comment: Tip: you can keep your scoping filter simple and isolated to just its scope by using `FilteredCatalog.Complement`. Start by filtering to the lowest scope, then filter each scope on its way up based on `FilteredCatalog.Complement` instead of `fullCatalog` each time. You won't have to Scope.App in your global level catalog, for example.

Comment: Tip #2: instead of various metadata keys like "Scope.App" and "Scope.Global" with throw away bool values, use just "Scope" and set its value to "Global" or "App".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exports and export metadata can be inherited. But I think part metadata cannot be inherited.

What you describe doesn't seem to be what I'd call *dynamic* scoping, since in fact the scope is fixed. It's just that you want it to automatically propagate to different parts based on what they export. Is that right?

What I've done for a very large MEF catalog in the past is not base it on what parts export, but rather what they import. For example, you have an "App" export. Anyone who imports it (transitively) automatically belong to the App scope (since they'd have to be in order to import it). Anything that doesn't get selected by that transitive import walk automatically bubbles up to the global scope. I actually did this with 4 scopes: lowest, middle, upper scopes, plus a global scope that everything else bubbles up to if they don't import the special scope-defining export. In each scope, there is a special MEF part that defines the anchor to that scope. This part is the `T` in `ExportFactory<T>` from the parent scope that creates instances of the lower scope. I use extension methods MEF already defines on FilteredCatalog to do the transitive import walk and it was actually very straightforward code.

The method below splits out a single catalog of all parts into scoped catalogs. It supports *n* scope depths. You can use the result to build up a `CompositionScopeDefinition`.

```
private static IImmutableDictionary<string, ComposablePartCatalog> GetScopedCatalogs(ComposablePartCatalog fullCatalog)
{
    Requires.NotNull(fullCatalog, "fullCatalog");

    // define the scopes, in order of lowest scope to highest.
    // The implicit one is the "" scope, which is global.
    string[] scopes = { typeof(DeepestScopePart).FullName, typeof(MiddleScopePart).FullName, typeof(UpperScopePart).FullName };

    var scopesAndCatalogs = ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, ComposablePartCatalog>().WithComparers(StringComparer.Ordinal);
    var catalog = fullCatalog; // start with the full catalog
    foreach (string scope in scopes)
    {
        // Pull out this scoped contract and everything that depends on it.
        var scopedCatalog = catalog
            .Filter(part => part.Exports(scope))
            .IncludeDependents(def => def.Cardinality != ImportCardinality.ZeroOrMore);
        scopesAndCatalogs = scopesAndCatalogs.Add(scope, scopedCatalog);

        // What's left over goes to the next scope up.
        catalog = scopedCatalog.Complement;
    }

    // define the implicit one (global catches every part that doesn't need a lower scope).
    scopesAndCatalogs = scopesAndCatalogs.Add(String.Empty, catalog);

    return scopesAndCatalogs;
}
```

I hope that helps. I think it will because it will get you where it sounds like you're going, which is implicitly scoped parts by virtue of what they import/export.

That said, you might consider using [Microsoft.Composition](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/) from NuGet which has a more complete scoping feature. But it comes with lots of limitations too, compared to the MEF found in .NET. So it may or may not be a good fit.

Comment: This works perfectly for me and is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Only problem is that IncludeDependents() generates new FilteredCatalog and will not be updated if new assembly has added to the catalog. 

This is important for me because I have two step loading process so only modules required for first UI has loaded as fast as possible and after it all others.

Comment: What you describe is a recomposition scenario. I didn't think `CompositionScopeDefinition` even supported that. In the app where I followed this pattern for years, I didn't use `CompositionScopeDefinition` since I too had a recomposition requirement. Instead, I had combinations of FilteredCatalogs (filtered using the above code) and would use AggregateCatalog to bring them together for each scope. Then I'd create containers based on an AggregateCatalog appropriate for that scope. That way I can add parts later by adding to the AggregateCatalog.

Comment: If startup perf is important to you, can you tell me whether your app is extensible, or if your catalog is completely "fixed" when you build your app? There are additional perf optimizations you can make for both startup and throughput if you take additional steps.

Comment: My applications is fully extensible. Modules are independent meaning there are no direct connections between modules. Also each module has own life cycle (init, activate, close). All the assemblies which contains [Export]/[Import] for module are defined by configuration and MEF catalogs are created dynamically by main application. Currently the core and authentication modules are loaded first and during login process all other modules are loaded. Earlier I loaded all assemblies at same time, but it took too long so I changed it.

Comment: Do the modules import or export types from *anything* external to the module (including those defined by your app)? If they are totally isolated, there's no need for recomposition or changing those FilteredCatalogs it would seem. There are some options to cache catalogs and even compositions for super fast startup and throughput, but they can get expensive to implement (at least until I manage to license a couple of assemblies for redistribution).

Comment: Most of modules only imports things from the core libraries, but there are also assemblies which are shared between different modules. I have tried to read all the articles and blog posts related how MEF is used inside visual studio and also little bit tested Roslyn System.Reflection.Metadata - https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MEFMetadata/

Comment: Hi Andrew. I'm having a little difficulty with the above code. I can't find the "Snapshot" method on FilteredCatalog.

Comment: @GeoffScott: the Snapshot() method is an extension method I wrote to increase performance in our particular scenario. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Most of modules only imports things from the core libraries, but there are also assemblies which are shared between different modules. I have tried to read all the articles and blog posts related how MEF is used inside visual studio and also little bit tested Roslyn System.Reflection.Metadata - https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MEFMetadata/